# Is this verse in the Quran found in the talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara

Because of that, We decreed upon the Children of Israel that whoever kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the land - it is as if he had slain mankind entirely. And whoever saves one - it is as if he had saved mankind entirely. And our messengers had certainly come to them with clear proofs. Then indeed many of them, [even] after that, throughout the land, were transgressors. Quran verse 5.32

So is this Quran verse found in the talmud in it's entirety or is only part of this Quran verse found in the talmud

Comment: Why might you be asking about this specific verse? Why do you think it is in the Talmud?

Comment: Let it be noted that the Talmud predates the Quran by at least one hundred years, and the Mishnah (which, as @Shalom pointed out, is the source of this quote) predates the Quran by four hundred years.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot the talmud includes the mishna, it's important to point that out

Answer (score 4):

Definitely something similar. Mishna Sanhedrin 4:5. *Sanhedrin* deals with the court systems; the context here is the additional safeguards in place for capital-punishment trials, because of the value of human life.

> לפיכך נברא אדם יחידי בעולם, ללמד שכל המאבד נפש אחת, מעלים עליו כאילו איבד עולם מלא; וכל המקיים נפש אחת, מעלים עליו כאילו קיים עולם מלא.
>
> Therefore the human was created alone in the world; to teach that one who destroys a single life is considered as if he had destroyed an entire world; and one who sustains a single life, it is considered as if he had sustained an entire world.

Comment: Shalom, I have checked the Talmud and I found the words you mentioned yet they were not exactly the same .. It reads: Therefore the man was created singly, to teach that he who destroys one soul of a human being, the Scripture considers him as if he should destroy a whole world, and him who saves one soul of Israel, the Scripture considers him as if he should save a whole world.
Why it was a different version or translation ? I give you the source
http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/t08/t0807.htm

Comment: @GamalThomas the original is in Hebrew! Naturally, you will find minor differences among translations. I believe your source is using the Soncino Press translation of the early 1900s; I did my own translation with an attempt at better readability. The only big difference is this: "whoever saves one soul [*of Israel*] ..." and that's due to textual variants in the original Hebrew.